# What permissions should i assign to an S3 bucket to only make it accessible from an EC2 instance using IAM roles?

Tags: permissions, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to setup an EC2 instance to have Get access to an S3 bucket with some private data. I set up a IAM role like so:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
       "Action": [
       "s3:Get*",
       "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I called the role "s3_bin_download_role"

I start my EC2 instances using the following command:

```
ec2-run-instances ami-4b143122 -n 1 -k us_east_key_pair -p s3_bin_download_role -g sg-????? -t t1.micro -z us-east-1a
```

This seems to work cleanly. But i haven't figured out how to verify that this EC2 instance actually has this role in it.

Anyway, once the instance starts up, i SSH into the machine and type:

```
curl http://my_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile.html
```

This gives me a "Access Denied" error.

I've setup my S3 bucket with NO permissions specified. This is obviously incorrect it seems. But i'm not sure what the minimal list of permissions is that i need to specify on the bucket to allow programs on this EC2 instance to read it.

As a bonus, i'd be very grateful if someone could tell me how i can figure out if an EC2 instance has a particular IAM role applied to it. The AWS console doesn't seem to have this information.

EDIT-

@slayedbylucifer is right but the details were very confusing so i'm adding the details here.

What's confusing is that you can in fact create IAM roles and immediately start up EC2 instances with those roles without creating any users or groups. Just use ec2-run-instances (from the cli tools) with the -p flag to pass in the name of the role you just created - the instance will start up with the role which you can verify by issuing the following command-

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<rolename>
```

If this works, then this instance will now run all requests that use the aws tools with permissions granted to it by that role.

BUT, what's happened behind the scenes is that since there are no users or groups defined, the user is implicitly the "root" user or whomever you are logged in as to the management console when you created the role. So, it's not that creating but not assigning the role means no one has access - ec2 instances started by the creator have access if the role gives access.

So now all you have to do is go to the S3 management console and give your bucket permissions for just yourself. And that's it.

Also, you can in fact use curl to retrieve the S3 objects even if they are not public- however, since it's not a aws tool, you need to explicitly pass in the hmac'ed aws tokens with the request which a tool like s3-curl.pl will do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THERE IS NOTHING SEE HERE... MOVE ON. 
THIS ANSWER IS NO MORE VALID AS AMAZON HAS ADDED THIS FEATURE SOMETIME BACK.**

<strike>Short Answer: No, you cannot apply IAM role to EC2 instance.</strike>

Either you define S3 Bucket policy on S3 end OR you define IAM roles and assign it to user/groups.

> This gives me a "Access Denied" error.

You have IAM role created but you have not assigned it to any IAM user. The default Access is "Deny". So you have to explicitly "Allow" access. And running `curl` as above makes me believe you want your S3 object be publicly accessible otherwise the command you are writing will not work.

Comment: You _can_ apply an IAM role to an EC2 instance. You just have to access the files using an aws tool (or saved credentials on the machine).